# Dropdown select extended options

Tags: html, css, select, html-select, dropdown

Im trying to make a dropdown. U have to search on the package number and you will get the detailed information so you can immediately see the correct price or sizes for that package.

```
            <div class="choosePackage">
            <label>
                <span>Package nr</span>
                <span>m3</span>
                <span>Size LxWxH</span>
                <span>Price</span>
                <span>Discount</span>
            </label>
            <select>
                <option value="">
                    <span class="optPackage"><strong>5528</strong></span>
                    <span class="optM3">9m3</span>
                    <span class="optLWH">1.00x2.00x3.40m</span>
                    <span class="optPrice">€70,00</span>
                    <span class="optDiscount">€280,00</span>
                </option>
            </select>         
        </div>
```

I made something like this, but you can't split the option.

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRPI.png)

Comment: You can't have child elements in an `option` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a solution, but have to run into a meeting. This should give you a basic idea however. Basically, you need to use JS to overlay a `styled dropdown` which will be linked to the actual drop down. Then you can style things to be different with in each option.

**Start by creating your drop down select**

You will want to make all the text as a single drop down

```
<select id="selectbox1">
    <option value="">Select an option&hellip;</option>
    <option value="basic">$100 Basic Package 3 Months</option>
    <option value="upgraded">$500 Upgraded Package 6 Months</option>
    <option value="expert">$1000 Expert Package 12 Months</option>
</select>
```

**Then you theoretically, jump through hoops using Javascript**

Here you will need to cache your options,  then hide the select to show your styled `div`.

```
 // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

// Hides the select element
$this.addClass('s-hidden');

// Wrap the select element in a div
$this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

// Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
$this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

// Cache the styled div
var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

// Show the first select option in the styled div
$styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());
```

**Now you will want to cache your styled div, and append some child elements into your div**

```
// Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            html: $this.children('option').eq(i).text()
            .split(' ').join(' <span style="color: red; font-weight:100;">'),
                rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    // Cache the list items
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');
```

You will want to use your `for loop` to append styling onto certain parts of your drop down. **[I have a basic mock up for you to check out as well.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTHkQ/1004/)**